# Set File access rule

Tags: c#, .net

The follow function works on windows XP, now im trying it with windows 7 it returns IdentityNotMappedException error what is wrong? i have also change the application requestedexecutionlevel to admin.

```
private static void file_accessdeny(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity accessdeny = System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(fileName);
        accessdeny.SetAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Deny));
        System.IO.File.SetAccessControl(fileName, accessdeny);
    }
    catch (System.Exception E)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(E.Message);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(E.Message, "access deny");
    }
}
```

Error: **System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException: Some or all identity references could not be translated**

Comment: Is you Windows 7 installation using the same language as the XP one?...use an IdentityReference instead of the "Everyone" string...so you don't have to worry about the culture in use at the time. Can use the well know SID for Everyone...SID = "S-1-1-0"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this instead in your code:

```
accessdeny.SetAccessRule(
   new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
   new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
   System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.FullControl,
   System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Deny));
```

The error message says "could not be translated" - this is Windows telling you that when it tried to find a SID for the "Everyone" group (i.e. translate)...it couldn't find it by that name.

One reason for that is when you are running Windows under a different locale. For instance in German the group is called "Jeder" instead.