# How to assign access rights "Everyone" to a directory

Tags: c#, .net, security, permissions, windows-identity

I encounter a problem to assign access rights to "**Everyone**" on a directory folder "**wwwroot**" on windows from my little programm in C#.
Here's how I do it.

```
//I also try with 'S-1-1-0'/'Everyone' but it's the same result 
string userPermission = "Everyone"  ;

DirectoryInfo myDirRoot = new DirectoryInfo(myArmsUpdate.InstallationPath);
DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirRoot.GetAccessControl();
FileSystemAccessRule myPermission = new FileSystemAccessRule(userPermission , FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow);

myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(myPermission);
myDirRoot.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
```

However I still get the same error:

> System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException

Comment: Try to Run your VS ->Run as administrator. Sometimes that may fix the exception.

Comment: The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215224/set-file-access-rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following,

```
DirectorySecurity sec = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
        // Using this instead of the "Everyone" string means we work on non-English systems.
        SecurityIdentifier everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
        sec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(everyone, FileSystemRights.Modify | FileSystemRights.Synchronize, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
        Directory.SetAccessControl(path, sec);
```

**Note:  You must be an administrator to make this work**

Comment: It's perfect ! Thanks . Now all work fine

Comment: That code looks suspiciously like what is [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5398398/109702). If you can copy code like this then the question should be closed as a duplicate.